# Mixing Vanilla JS with jQuery, getting variable is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Really poor situation where I've had to hack new code into some really old code and to get it working I've had to inline a bunch of jQuery and some vanilla JS. Now the jQuery is all working fine (a win) but the vanilla JS when called gives

Uncaught ReferenceError: reset is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: checkAnswers is not defined

I've tried to do jq.reset() from the console but this was still not defined.

Here's the inline JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
            var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);  

            (function ($) {

            $(document).ready(function () {    

            /* Drag and Drop */
            //var container = document.getElementById("health");
            //var content = container.innerHTML;

            var correctAnswers = [
              "fish and seafood",
              "meat and small goods",
              "poultry and game",
              "dairy and egg-based foods",
              "wet dishes, soups, stock and sauces",
              "fruits including rock melon, watermelon, blueberries and fruit salad",
              "pre-made salads",
              "pate and soft cheeses",
              "ice-cream",
              "cooked rice and pasta"
            ];
            var answers = [];

            function checkAnswers() {
              correctAnswers.sort();
              answers.sort();
              var result = true;

              if (correctAnswers.length !== answers.length) {
                result = false;
                $("#incomplete").show();
              } else if (correctAnswers.length == answers.length) {
                for (var i = correctAnswers.length; i--; ) {
                  if (correctAnswers[i] !== answers[i]) {
                    result = false;
                    $("#incomplete").hide();
                    $("#incorrect").show();
                  }
                }
              }

              if (result) {
                $("#incorrect").hide();
                $("#incomplete").hide();
                $("#correct").show();
              }
            }

            function allowDrop(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev) {
              ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
              var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
              answers.push(data);
              console.log(correctAnswers);
              console.log(answers);
              ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }

            function dropOut(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
              var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
              var index = answers.indexOf(data);
              answers.splice(index, 1);
              console.log(correctAnswers);
              console.log(answers);
              ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }

            function reset() {
              var container = document.getElementById("health");
              container.innerHTML = html;
              answers = [];
              document.getElementById(".dropable-area").reset();
            }

            if ($('#health').length){
                var html;
                window.onload = function() {
                    html = document.getElementById("health").innerHTML;
                }; 
            }

            $("#health").on("click",".correctKey",function() {
              $("#health").find(".dropbox").each(function(index) {
                $(this).text(correctAnswers[index]);
                answers = correctAnswers;
              });
            });

          });
        }(jq));
        </script>
```

The HTML where its being called, the button with reset() and checkAnswers() are failing, I thought about stripping this out and putting it in a seperate script, but it also has jQuery which needs to be wrapped to protect its version from the older one also used in the file.

```
<div class="container drag" id="health">
  <div class="row dropable-area">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row answers-area">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default answers">
        <div class="panel-body" ondrop="dropOut(event)">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="fish and seafood">fish and seafood</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="meat and small goods">meat and small goods</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="packets of dry food">packets of dry food</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="poultry and game">poultry and game</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="wet dishes, soups, stock and sauces">wet dishes, soups, stock and sauces</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dairy and egg-based foods">dairy and egg-based foods</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="pre-made salads">pre-made salads</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="raw vegetables">raw vegetables</p>
              <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="pate and soft cheeses">pate and soft cheeses</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="uncooked rice and pasta">uncooked rice and pasta</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="ice-cream">ice-cream</p>
              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="cooked rice and pasta">cooked rice and pasta</p>

              <p class="answer" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="fruits including rock melon, watermelon, blueberries and fruit salad">fruits including rock melon, watermelon, blueberries and fruit salad</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottom-area">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="checkAnswers()">Check Answers</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default correctKey">Answer Key</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
      <div class="messages">
        <div class="alert alert-success" id="correct" style="display:none;">
        <p><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully identified the hazards!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" id="incomplete" style="display:none;">
          <p><strong>Warning!</strong> You havn't finished identifying all the hazards.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" id="incorrect" style="display:none;">
          <p><strong>Oh snap!</strong> It doesn't look like you have the correct hazards identified!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because inline methods like `onlclick` expect functions in global namespace...but yours are inside the IIFE and `$(document).ready` so are not scoped in global namespace. Use jQuery event listeners instead of `onclick`

Comment: I'll give it a go, cheers!